# On facebook, will applying for an android review black my iOS access already reviewed

Tags: android, ios, facebook, oauth, review

I have successfully passed the iOS review on facebook and my app is using it at the moment.
Now I need to pass the android one.
Will it 'block' or 'disable' my iOS access during the review or is it independent? (in the best world it shouldn't)

Comment: After thought, since the app has already validated permissions for iOS, I think that I don't need to review it again for Android. I mean when I submitted for iOS my app had to be functional (with a xcode file), right now I don't see any place where I can submit only for android and I can login so I guess once the permissions have been validated it is working for all platforms.

Comment: Correct. If you just want to use the same permissions your are good to go

Comment: Thanks you very much!